# Automatically parse json attributes into a new object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have incoming data in `json` format looking like this:

*Raw data*:

```
{
  "data": [{
      "id": "Device_6",
      "type": "SensingDevice",
      "Battery": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "4.08",
        "metadata": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "voltage"
          }
        }
      },
      "DO": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "5.71",
        "metadata": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "mg/l"
          }
        }
      },
      "Humidity": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "57.30",
        "metadata": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "percent"
          }
        }
      },
      "PH": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "14.00",
        "metadata": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z"
          }
        }
      },
      "temperature": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "41.00",
        "metadata": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "celsius"
          }
        }
      },
      "waterTemperature": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "29.69",
        "metadata": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "celsius"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "subscriptionId": "59d5eeec4f3db340052d618c"
}
```

For a specific application purpose, i need to transform this complex `JSON` into a simple `key:value` format.

So I'm using this code in node js with node-json-transform package:

```
 var map_data = {
           list:'data',
            item :  { Battery: 'Battery.value',
                        DO: 'DO.value',
                        Humidity: 'Humidity.value',
                        PH: 'PH.value',
                        temperature: 'temperature.value',
                        waterTemperature: 'waterTemperature.value', },
    };
   console.log (map_data)

         var dataTransform = DataTransform(data, map_data);
         var data_result = dataTransform.transform();
```

And the output looks like what I want :

```
[ { Battery: '4.08',
    DO: '5.71',
    Humidity: '57.30',
    PH: '14.00',
    temperature: '41.00',
    waterTemperature: '29.69' } ]
```

But now, what if I don't know the name of the attributes? 
So I tried to make it automatic to discover the keys:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data.data[0]); 
var keysvalues = '';
    for (i=2; i < keys.length; i++) {
        keysvalues += keys[i]+':"'+ keys[i] + '.value",';
    }
var item = '{'+keysvalues+'}'; 
var map_data = {
            list:"data", 
            item,
    };
 var dataTransform = DataTransform(data, map_data);
 var data_result = dataTransform.transform();
```

This is not working because the object `map_data.item` is a "fake" object where I manually added the `{}`, so it is recognized like a string :

```
console.log(map_data)
{ list: 'data',
  item: '{Battery:"Battery.value",DO:"DO.value",Humidity:"Humidity.value",PH:"PH.value",temperature:"temperature.value",waterTemperature:"waterTemperature.value",}' }
```

Can you help me on how to make the item object a real object so I can parse the `JSON` automatically in the format I want?

Comment: If you get json in the string from, then it is enough to call `var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(your_json_string)`. Now `myJsonObject` behaves like a usual js object with all properties. You can also call `JSON.stringify(myJsonObject)` to serialize your object. Sometimes, like in jquery ajax calls, methods return already parsed json. So you just use them as usual js object. Read the documentation of a method to know the behavior.

Comment: I already tried to parse into JSON but I can't make it work. I always have a "unexpected token" error...I just tried also the stringify call, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Show your json string and how you call `JSON.parse()`, and where the error appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to create a map given the 'value' property of all the nested objects. This means you have to filter out the keys of your original object that aren't Objects or that don't have the 'value' prop.
Here's how I would do it (I've used ES6 to avoid verboseness).

```
const isObject = (o) =>
  o instanceof Object && o.constructor === Object;

const getSingleMap = (datum, prop) => {
  const mapKeys = Object.keys(datum).filter(key => isObject(datum[key]) && datum[key][prop]);
  const obj = {};
  mapKeys.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = datum[key][prop];
  });

  return obj;
}

const getMap = (rawData, prop) =>
  rawData.data.map(datum => getSingleMap(datum, prop));
```

To use it, simply call `const res = getMap(rawData, 'value');`.

```
/*
res == [
  {
    "Battery": "4.08",
    "DO": "5.71",
    "Humidity": "57.30",
    "PH": "14.00",
    "temperature": "41.00",
    "waterTemperature": "29.69"
  }
];
*/
```

Below is provided a more elegant `getSingleMap` implementation.

```
getSingleMap = (datum, prop) => {
  const mapKeys = Object.keys(datum).filter(key => isObject(datum[key]) && datum[key][prop]);
  return mapKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = datum[key][prop];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Update: I've also create an npm package out of this, it's called **json2kv**, and you can find its source [here](https://github.com/jkomyno/json2kv)

Comment: Thanks ! It is exactly what i want, to extract the attribute.value field, if it exists. I tested your code and it worked perfectly !

Comment: Cool, glad to have helped :)

Comment: Please check the latest edit for an even better and more elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks, can I ask you another question ? I just figured out that I have one situation where it can be more complex. If i have the attribute "location", then the value i want is not in location.value, but in location.value.coordinates. How can I pass this exception (if data.data[0].location exists ?)

Comment: Please open another question on StackOverflow and post the link below this comment, since SO's comments aren't the best place to provide answers.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I found a way to do it anyway !

Comment: Anyway @Charlotte, in the future you might want to use this npm package that I have adapted from my answer.
Source: https://github.com/jkomyno/json2kv
Npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2kv

Comment: Nice ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

**Raw JavaScript Code**
can change `if` constrain to handle ***array*** it will not handle array if your DATA field wasn't Array it work properly

if your json have array in it it will very complex(not about code just about wat u want as a result).
another proplem is `key : value` format will override many of your information

**BUT** if you want do it any way you can simply do :

```
  function ToSimpleJson(json , result , prefix)
{
   for(key in json)
   {
       if(typeof json[key]!="object" )
           result[prefix+key] = json[key]
       else if (!json[key].length) // Object
           ToSimpleJson(json[key], result , (key+"."))
       else // Array (But will Override if have more than 1 index)
       {
           json[key].forEach(function (x)
           {    
               ToSimpleJson(x, result , (key + "."))
           })

       }
   }

return result
}
```

and call function with empty result and empty prefix

```
ToSimpleJson(json , {} , "")
```

and result is :

```
{
    "data.id" : "Device_6",
    "data.type" : "SensingDevice",
    "Battery.type" : "Number",
    "Battery.value" : "4.08",
    "timestamp.type" : "DateTime",
    "timestamp.value" : "2017-11-09T14:49:02.00Z",
    "unit.type" : "Text",
    "unit.value" : "celsius",
    "DO.type" : "Number",
    "DO.value" : "5.71",
    "Humidity.type" : "Number",
    "Humidity.value" : "57.30",
    "PH.type" : "Number",
    "PH.value" : "14.00",
    "temperature.type" : "Number",
    "temperature.value" : "41.00",
    "waterTemperature.type" : "Number",
    "waterTemperature.value" : "29.69",
    "subscriptionId" : "59d5eeec4f3db340052d618c"
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i want only the attribute.value field. I have attribute.type, attribute.metadata that I don't want. So I need a way to get out all the attribute.value field without knowing the attribute name.
I edited the question so you can see better the original json data format

Comment: use `for(var k in json)` and k will be attribute name  and to anything in `for`

Comment: Ok thanks, this is also good to know if i want to extract alll the values of my json into key:value format. It works too !

Comment: u can also add Array Index to prefix in `else` to avoid override